# Polylang Pro Causes 404 When I modify URLs

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I use **Polylang Pro** plugin on my Wordpress website and it works well but when I change the permalinks settings or sometimes add a new CPT it causes 404 on the secondary language pages.

After I go to the Polylang settings and click on "Save Changes" in "URL modifications" everything comes back to normal.

This issue has happened on many websites I've worked with and how can I prevent this?

Thank you